# Submitting a Facebook open graph action without a test server

Tags: facebook-graph-api, submit, action

I've created 2 Open graph actions for my facebook app. It appears that the submission process assumes that I have a separate test server to submit for testing.  However, in my case we do all testing on some local machines and then have our real server.  Is there any techniques for submitting an action in this situation?  If I move my code as-is users will get errors as the actions are approved - right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should keep the Open graph related call in `try catch` statements, so that user does not encounter error. it just will not publish the activity for users untill it gets approved and as soon as it gets approved it will start working for all users.

Comment: how will it work for the test user that facebook uses to test?

Comment: facebook uses your app's auth dialog preview user for which it works, you can try with that test account. it works for developers, admin and auth dialog preview user even when action is not approved.